Is X-Ray-Emission-Containing Phosphorescence possible or is it limited to Immediate-Emission XRF?
This was a random thought that I wanted to follow up on. I know some materials can take in and kick out X-Rays in XRF (Though most x-ray scintillators tend to emit mostly visible light, not x-rays). However, to my knowledge XRF behaves a bit differently from UV/Visible Fluorescence, so I don't know if Phosphorescene is possible. Is "delayed emission" of any kind possible for XRF?
I remember hearing about some research that made mention of weak x-ray-based phosphorescent signatures from Calcium Tungstate (an old scintillator based on the natural mineral Scheelite), but I cannot find said research, nor anything similar to it that clearly states that it's possible.

In x-ray scintillators, the light comes indirectly via excitation by electrons. And they do fluoresce, but they tend to capture their own fluorescent photons. If they don't, you see "K-escape".
